# Python: package docx can't open a docx

Tags: python-2.7, python-docx

I want to use python to open a word. I use win32com and it works. I find a package named docx and I really think it is very useful. But when I used it to open a wordfile, it raised valueError.

> valueError: file '1.doc' is not a Word file, content type is    'applicationnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.themeManager+xml'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar problem discussed here: [can't open a .docx file #229](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/229)
It looks like that it doesn't work with old doc files.
Try converting the doc file to docx - as lieuzhenghong did in the link - see if that solves the error

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It works. My file is `.doc`,this lib doesn't support `the legacy pre-Word 2007 forma`t.In its doc I find it :You can open any Word 2007 or later file this way (.doc files from Word 2003 and earlier won’t work). I still need to convert it to `.docx` just like the old way I used to do with the lib `win32com`,I used that to convert the `.docx` to `.txt`.